# Conditionals in Elisp's cl-loop facility

Tags: loops, lisp, elisp, continue

I'm trying to wrap my head around Elisp's cl-loop facility but can't seem to find a way to skip elements.  Here's an artificial example to illustrate the problem: I'd like to loop over a list of integers and get a new list in which all odd integers from the original list are squared.  The even integers should be omitted.

According to the documentation of cl-loop, I should be able to do this:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3)
      if (evenp i)
        append (list)
      else
        for x = (* x x)
        and append (list x))
```

The desired output is `'(1 9)` instead I get an error:

```
cl--parse-loop-clause: Expected a `for' preposition, found (list x)
```

Apparently the `and` doesn't work as expected but I don't understand why.  (I'm aware that I could simplify the else block to consist of only one clause such that the `and` isn't needed anymore.  However, I'm interested in situations where you really have to connect several clauses with `and`.)

Second part of the question: Ideally, I would be able to write this:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3)
      if (evenp i)
        continue
      for x = (* x x)
      append (list x))
```

Continue is a very common way to skip iterations in other languages.  Why doesn't cl-loop have a continue operator?  Is there a simple way to skip elements that I overlooked (simpler than what I tried in the first example)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Common Lisp it is not possible to write such a LOOP. See the [LOOP Syntax](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm).

There is a set of variable clauses on the top. But you can't use one like `FOR` later in the main clause. So in an `IF` clause you can't use `FOR`. If you want to introduce a local variable, then you need to introduce it at the top as a `WITH` clause and set it later in the body.

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3)
      with x
      if (evenp i)
        append (list)
      else
        do (setf x (* i i))
        and append (list x))
```

`LOOP` in Common Lisp also has no `continue` feature. One would use a conditional clause.

Note, that Common Lisp has a more advanced iteration construct as a library `ITERATE`. It does not exist for Emacs Lisp, though.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you.  It's strange that cl-loop is so powerful and yet makes you jump through hoops when you want something simple like continue.

Comment: @tmalsburg `LOOP` serves as an example both for and against the virtues of Lisp macros.

Comment: @Rainer -- Looking forward to the day [`iterate`](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/Don_0027t-Loop-Iterate.html) is added to Emacs Lisp.

Comment: @AaronMiller -- are you suggesting that implementing continue would be impossible or at least difficult in the context of the loop macro?

Comment: @tmalsburg Not at all; what I'm saying is that, while `LOOP` is an extremely powerful and flexible facility of the language, to the extent that it has [its own chapter](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node235.html) in *Common Lisp: The Language*, it is also an extremely subtle and complex topic requiring great mastery to understand in depth, to the extent that it *needs* its own chapter in *Common Lisp: The Language*.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3)
      if (oddp i) collect (* i i))
```

That would solve your sample problem.

Comment: Sure, that solves it.  But as I said, it was an artificial example and I wanted to understand the use of `and`.  Thanks for the response anyway.

Answer (score 3):

And here's another without `loop` (yes, I know you asked for `loop`):

```
(let ((ns  ()))
  (dolist (n  '(1 2 3))
    (when (oddp n) (push (* n n) ns)))
  (nreverse ns))
```

And without even `cl-lib` (which defines `oddp`):

```
(let ((ns  ()))
  (dolist (n  '(1 2 3))
    (unless (zerop (mod n 2)) (push (* n n) ns)))
  (nreverse ns))
```

Everything about such definitions is clear -- just *Lisp*. Same with @abo-abo's examples.

`loop` is a separate *language*.  Its purpose is to express common iteration scenarios, and for that it can do a good job.  *But Lisp it is not.* ;-)  It is a domain-specific language for expressing iteration.  And it lets you make use of Lisp sexps, fortunately.

(Think of the Unix `find` command -- similar. It's very handy, but it's another language unto itself.)

[No flames, please.  Yes, I know that `dolist` and all the rest are essentially no different from `loop` -- neither more nor less *Lisp*.  But they are ***lispier*** than `loop`.  Almost anything is lispier than `loop`.]

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  I was surprised to find loop for the reasons that you mention.  It doesn't seem idiomatic.  I'm writing a source for emacs-helm and since most other sources use cl-loop I decided to follow that for consistency.

Comment: @tmalsburg: Some people are great fans of `loop`; others are not. Those who use it a lot speak its language fluently and it feels natural to them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a loop solution:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3)
   when (oddp i) collect (* i i))
```

Here's a functional solution:

```
(delq nil
      (mapcar (lambda(x) (and (oddp x) (* x x)))
              '(1 2 3)))
```

Here's a slightly different solution (be careful with `mapcan` - it's destructive):

```
(mapcan (lambda(x) (and (oddp x) (list (* x x))))
        '(1 2 3))
```